# MS Teams bot fails to establish outgoing call

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am using the AudioVideoPlayback sample from [GitHub Comms Samples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples).
I modified the code to create an outgoing call to my Teams client.
After getting the "Establishing" state notification, there is no more activity for about a minute. After that, I receive the Terminated state notification and a missed call notification in the client.

Could you please let me know if this functionality is supported and how can I investigate further the issue?

Thank you,
Bogdan

Comment: This should work. The most likely issue is that media is not establishing for that call because of bad configuration on the client (Cert name mismatch, not using SSL, port not opened, etc.). See if you can check that.

Also, try filing an issue here instead of reporting here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues

Comment: Thank you Bill! I was reluctant to open an issue there as the sample itself does not try to establish outgoing call. I will open one now.